# Issues when installing the application in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing iPhone applications. I have to use push notification for my iPhone application. For that, I have created new provisioning profiles for my iPhone application. I have configured for APNS. Before installing this profile, the application was working in my device. But after installing the profile, I am getting a message. That is;

Failed to upload "myapps.app".

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Just i have restarted xcode. After that it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell the exact error description that you observed?
Drag your new profile on to itunes, sync your device, then drag your app to itunes and sync now. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Actually  I did not get any error messages. But I got the solution. That is, just i have restarted xcode. After that it is working fine.